# Wording: closest date vs nearest date?

Tags: meaning, comparatives, dates

Which sounds more natural?

> The closest date is ...

or

> The nearest date is ...

Context: It is a variable name in a software application I rewrite, which - in short - expresses the most close date to a given date.

---

*closest date* yields 55k results of Google, vs 33k for *nearest date*.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is any significant difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tend to think, that *closest* has a more temporal semantic, whereas *nearest* is more *spatial*.

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I don't sense the temporal vs. spatial distinction that you evidently feel...

Comment: I'm no native speaker, so I can't really tell where I get this distinction from. Thanks again for the quick reply.